# Conversion of Pilot's license from Transport canada to FAA post minor heart attack

Tags: faa

My husband got his license back in Canada but wants to move to the US, FAA is giving him a hard time in conversion. Is it even possible?

Comment: What specific problem is he having? Is it really his pilot license that is the problem, or is it actually his medical certificate?